# Restarting the server in the JEE applications

Tags: web, intellij-idea, servlets, java-ee-5, liveserver

I'm working in a project as web project with JEE in intellig. When modifying a code in a servlett the changes doesn't made. I may resart the server if i want to see the changes . This is unconfortable for me to restart the server every change. So what's the solution?

I try to enable  build project automatically setting but it doesn't work and Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to start the server in debug mode, also try to enable the File | Settings | Tools | Actions on Save | Build project (which is same as Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler |  Build project automatically) and File | Settings | Advanced Settings | Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running.
Now the IDEA will auto-update the project in your case.